# Find the months with min and max of sales for each year in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, max, min

I have a set of data from 1950 to 2020 about the units sold for each month in each year:

```
  Date            Units_Sold
  <chr>                <dbl>        
1 1/2020                1000         
2 2/2020                2000          
3 3/2020                2500       
4 4/2020                1300        
5 5/2020                4355       
6 6/2020                1233
# ... with 1,190 more rows
```

I'm trying to find:

1. the months having least (min) and most (max) units sold for each year.
2. the year having the maximum difference between least and most units sold.

If I used the following code, it's going to give me the min and max for all the years, not the month of each year with min and max unit solds.

```
filter(data, data$Units_Sold==min(data$Units_Sold)) %>% select(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

First separate your `date` column into month and year so you can group by those variables (year is important for each of your question) and calculate min and max value for each pair (month, year):

```
summary_df <- data %>% 
    separate(date, c("month", "year"), sep = "/") %>% 
    group_by(month, year) %>% 
    summarise(type = c("min", "max"), value = range(value), .groups = "drop")
```

For first question, take min and max of `Units_Sold` grouped by `year` and filter only range values:

```
month_df <- summary_df %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    filter(value %in% range(value)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

To find year with maximum difference again group by `year` and calculate difference between difference between min and max:

```
year_df <- summary_df %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(year_diff = diff(range(value)))
```